# Path issue with node.js and SQLLite

Tags: node.js

i have the following code (shortened it a bit)

`dbInterface.js`

```
const sqlConnection = require('sqlite3').verbose()
const data = require('./data.js')
//open database --> uses create/readwrite per default
let db = new sqlConnection.Database('./db/test_db.db', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to database')
  }
  console.log('Connected to the chinook database.')
})

exports.dbFunctions = {
  userPresent: userPresent,
  createTable: createTable,
  tablePresent: tablePresent,
  dropTable: dropTable,
  dropAll: dropTable,
  addUser: addUser,
  deleteUser: deleteUser,
  showTableContent: showTableContent,
  addHistory: addHistory,
  clearHistory: clearHistory,
  removeLastHistoryEntry: removeLastHistoryEntry,
  getHistory: getHistory
}

function userPresent (id) {
  // noinspection SqlResolve
  const statement = 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE pk_user_id == ' + id
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.all(statement, (err, row) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('reject')
        reject(false)
        return
      }
      console.log('resolve')
      resolve(true)
    })
  })
}
```

When I access the exported functions on the same folder level everything works fine.

As soon as I call the functions from another level like `/tests/db_tests.js`

I can work with for example `userPresent` but the database cannot establish a connection unless I change it to:

```
let db = new sqlConnection.Database('../db/test_db.db', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error connecting to database')
  }
  console.log('Connected to the chinook database.')
})
```

See I changed the path location from `./db/test_db.db` to `../db/test_db.db`

Since my app access the dbInterface from many different locations I feel very stuck to solve this issue.

I also tried it with an `index.js` that is on the same level lile the `dbInterface.js` and contained only this

```
exports.dbInterface = require('./dbInterface')
```

But this also didn't work.

Can anyone help out please?

Answer (score 0):

try absolute path

```
const path = require('path');
let dbPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'db', 'test_db.db');
```

Comment: this didn't work but it helped me to find a working solution which is:
`const dbPath = path.join(process.cwd()).split('datastorage')[0] + '\\datastorage\\db\\test_db.db'`

thank you